# Efficient algorithm to remove bad numbers from sets

Tags: algorithm, computer-science

Given are a number of finite sets of integers, for example:

```
A = {1,2,3}
B = {2,3,4}
C = {3,4,5}
```

and also a number, for example 6. The question is to determine from the sets the numbers that cannot be used to sum 6 by selecting one number from each set. For example the 1 in A is valid, because 1+2+3=6 (the 2 coming from B and the 3 from C). The 5 from the C is not valid, because you can't sum to 6 by using the 5 (you will always get at least 1+2+5=8).

How can you do this efficiently?

Comment: Could 1 be in the B-set as well, ie. both A and B contains 1?

Comment: you should be able to obtain some sort of `(logN)^3 ` [i think] algorithm by using binary searches and elimination of invalid halfs.  assuming sets are sorted

Comment: @aaa: If they weren't sorted, it would still only take N*logN time to sort them, and so your complexity would still apply.

Comment: @Jer I adjusted the comment slightly - i think `3N*logN` isnt right

Comment: @aaa: You would need at least Theta(N) since you need to read all of the sets (assuming a RAM, not PRAM).

Comment: @Jules: *the* question is... *"What are the requirements?"*  In other words: what are the constraints.  The computer itself is a mechanical device that has constraints: how big can the integers be? how many integers can you have in one set? how many set?  For example if there can be billions of integers ranging from [0...2^512] and billions of set, you probably won't be able to solve it...

Comment: @St3fan: this is not homework. I do not even study computer science, although I am interested in it. @Lasse: Yes, the same number can appear multiple times. @SyntaxT3rr0r: The sets aren't too large. I'm currently using a brute force algorithm that just looks at every possible choice. This still completes in somewhat acceptable time, albeit slowly (that is, hours, not centuries). The sets aren't fixed size, if the algorithm becomes faster I will be able to solve bigger problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I assume 3 sets is just an example and the actual number of sets isn't fixed*

Let's say we have `m` sets with `n` numbers total and maximum possible sum `S`. (In your example `m = 3`, `n = 9`, `S = 12`).

Then question whether number `t` from set `s` can be used to achieve sum `x` is equivalent to the following: can the other `m - 1` sets (except set `s`) add up to a number `x - t`?

This problem has pseudo-polynomial solution of complexity `O(n*S)`, much like the one for [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_dynamic_programming_solution).

Therefore, you can solve this problem for each combination of `m - 1` sets and it'll give you `O(n*S*m)` complexity.

Comment: @Jeremiah Yes, if you can have negative numbers. Even if `x = 10`, you can still have solution employing numbers `100` and `-90`.

Comment: I forgot about that case.  The question does say "integers."

Comment: Thanks, this improved the performance a lot! My sets are often quite dense, like A = {1,2,3,4,6}, B = {1,3,4,5,6}, C = {1,2,4,5,6}, etc. So while my old brute force method would generate 5^n pairs and check them, your method does it in linear time :)